# Why is pip ignoring the latest version of my package?

Tags: python, installation, pip, packaging, twine

I am currently developing and testing a package named [game.py](https://test.pypi.org/project/game.py).
While trying to install the newest version (0.0.2) with pip, it would only download 0.0.1.
`pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ game.py==0.0.2` did not help me either as that just spit out a

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement game.py==0.0.2 (from versions: 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for game.py==0.0.2
```

I am using `python -m build` and `python -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*` to build and upload to testpypi.
These all work fine, and testpypi clearly knows that 0.0.2 exists, as the page for the version exists and has download files attached.
What could be going on?

Comment: Same error here. I see the ver 0.0.2 on the testpypi web page too, can directly download files from there, but not with `pip`. (just to confirm, cannot answer why is it so)